# Upgrade PHP from 7.2 to 7.4

Tags: php

So, I'm on my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04) with multiple versions of PHP installed. I'm attempting to switch between `7.2` and `7.4`. Here's my approach:-

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config php
```

```
There are 3 choices for the alternative php (providing /usr/bin/php).

  Selection    Path             Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        auto mode
  1            /usr/bin/php7.2   72        manual mode
* 2            /usr/bin/php7.4   74        manual mode
  3            /usr/bin/php8.0   80        manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number:
```

and order a server restart:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

Why then, back in my browser with a `phpinfo()` request does the system report I'm still on `7.2`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache don't know what you want. Try this:
1st disable the php7.2 module

```
a2dismod php7.2
```

after that, enable the php7.4

```
a2enmod php7.4
```

And restart apache

```
systemctl restart apache2
```